# Tableau: ensure data integrity in collaboration environment

Tags: tableau-api

I am deploying Tableau throughout our department and need to ensure that data cannot be altered in Tableau files once they are shared by the final user, before review.

I could not find any way to make the data source read-only in .twbx files

Comment: Read about extracts

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm not supposed to ask for clarification but, how are you deploying Tableau? If the others are end users, I would suggest Tableau Server or Online depending on your preferences. This would give the end users access to the visualizations you are building but they would not be able to edit the sources.